# Set Wavelength Min and Max for Raster in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro

I have a raster with 16 bands and I need to add the wavelength min and max but the methods I am using aren't working. I am using ArcGIS Pro and I used the Set Raster Properties in Geoprocessing but I'm not sure how to add the min and max wavelength for individual bands in the key properties section.

I tried using python and arcpy.SetRasterProperties_management. arcpy.SetRasterProperties_management(r"Data\GIS\ENVI\JanJun_2022_Barbados\2022_06_24_All Bands.tif\Blue", key_properties = "WavelengthMin:465; WavelengthMax:515"). It says it has succeeded but there have been no changes to the properties of the raster.

Does anyone know what I need to do to set the min and max wavelength for each band?[image][image]

Comment: Deleting and reposting isn't going to get your Question answered sooner, but it might  spur the SE anti-spam defenses to lock out your account.

Comment: The question got closed because I didn't include the code in the text (I had it as a photo). So I was just reposting it so I could include the code that's all.

Comment: That's what the `Edit` button is for. Then it can be reviewed. Please take the [Tour] to better understand how this exchange works.

Comment: I did that and it wasn't working but thank you.